# Best way to select records that having more recent date from grouped duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestToDelete](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RawEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NULL,
    [ValidationDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (1, N'a@a.ru', N'aaa@a.ru', 11, CAST(N'2017-02-07 14:00:30.300' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (2, N'a@a.ru', N'aaa@a.ru', 11, CAST(N'2017-02-07 14:00:52.347' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (3, N'a@a.ru', N'aaa@a.ru', 11, CAST(N'2017-02-07 14:00:58.117' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (4, N'a@a.ru', N'aaa@a.ru', 22, CAST(N'2017-02-07 14:01:08.360' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (5, N'b@b.ru', N'bbb@b.ru', 11, CAST(N'2017-02-07 14:01:21.783' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (6, N'b@b.ru', N'bbb@b.ru', 11, CAST(N'2017-02-07 14:01:29.310' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (7, N'b@b.ru', N'bbb@b.ru', 22, CAST(N'2017-02-07 14:01:37.050' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (8, NULL, N'bbb@b.ru', 0, CAST(N'2017-02-07 14:02:10.643' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (9, NULL, N'aaa@a.ru', 0, CAST(N'2017-02-07 14:02:22.160' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (10, N'anew@a.ru', N'aaa@a.ru', 11, CAST(N'2017-02-07 15:30:01.637' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (11, N'anew@a.ru', N'aaa@a.ru', 11, CAST(N'2017-02-07 15:30:06.657' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestToDelete] ([id], [Email], [RawEmail], [Status], [ValidationDate]) VALUES (12, N'anew@a.ru', N'aaa@a.ru', 11, CAST(N'2017-02-07 15:30:12.160' AS DateTime))
```

And I need to select records (`Email`, `RawEmail` and `Status` fields) that occurs 3 or more times and have more recent date. In this table it is

```
'anew@a.ru | aaa@a.ru | 11'
```

and not

```
'a@a.ru | aaa@a.ru | 11'
```

because `anew@a.ru` has more recent date

The query to do this selection:

```
select * from
(
   select email, rawEmail, Status, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rawEmail ORDER BY vdate DESC) num 
   from
      (select max([ValidationDate]) vdate, email, rawEmail, Status
         from TestToDelete where status in (11, 22)
         group by rawEmail, email, status 
         having count(*) > 2
      ) tmp 
)final where num = 1
```

Is it possible to do this with less subqueries (not 3 like now)?

---

UPDATE: 
Expected output for 3 or more occurs:

```
anew@a.ru | aaa@a.ru | 11
```

Expected output for 2 or more occurs:

```
anew@a.ru | aaa@a.ru | 11
b@b.ru | bbb@b.ru | 11
```

Comment: do you mean 3 or more records having the latest datetime?

Comment: @vkp 3 or more identical records one of which having the latest datetime.

Comment: @vkp if one tuple has dates 2010, 2011, 2016 and second tuple has 1997, 1998 and 2017 - I need the second because 2017 more recent.

Comment: please show your expected ouput,is it one record or total 3

Comment: You are about as close as you can get. You have to rank a group subset and take the best ranked row. Since you can't do both of those operations in one query you will need at least two queries.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I have updated post. Expected output is distinct tuples, but if this tuples have the same RawEmail I need only tuple, that have resent date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**`with (common table expression)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), 
and [**`count() over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

If we can partition the `count()` by `RawEmail, Status` then:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        rn = row_number() over (
            partition by RawEmail
            order by ValidationDate desc
            )
        , cnt = count(*) over (
            partition by RawEmail, status
            )
        , *
    from TestToDelete
    where status in (11, 22)
    )
select * 
from cte o 
where o.rn=1 
  and o.cnt > 2
```

results: http://rextester.com/WYVZ86149

```
+----+-----+----+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| rn | cnt | id |   Email   | RawEmail | Status |   ValidationDate    |
+----+-----+----+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |   7 | 12 | anew@a.ru | aaa@a.ru |     11 | 07.02.2017 15:30:12 |
+----+-----+----+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

If we can not partition the `count()` by `RawEmail, Status` then:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        rn = row_number() over (
            partition by RawEmail
            order by ValidationDate desc
            )
        , cnt = count(*) over (
            partition by RawEmail
            )
        , *
    from TestToDelete
    where status in (11, 22)
    )
select * 
from cte o 
where o.rn=1 
  and o.cnt > 2
  and exists (
    select 1
      from cte i 
      where i.RawEmail = o.RawEmail
        and i.Email != o.Email
      )
```

results: http://rextester.com/YTQ30810

```
+----+-----+----+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| rn | cnt | id |   Email   | RawEmail | Status |   ValidationDate    |
+----+-----+----+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |   7 | 12 | anew@a.ru | aaa@a.ru |     11 | 07.02.2017 15:30:12 |
+----+-----+----+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The first query do exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT *,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RawEmail
                       ORDER BY ValidationDate DESC) AS rn,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Email, Status) AS cnt
   FROM TestToDelete
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1 AND cnt >= 3
ORDER BY ValidationDate DESC
```

The query uses a *Common Table Expression* that employs window functions:

- `RANK` is used in order to get the latest per `RawEmail` record or records (in case of ties)
- `COUNT` is used in order to determine the population of each `Email, Status` slice

Comment: It only return top 1. I need all tuples, that occurs 3 or more times. But if this tuples have the same `RawEmail` - I want to take tuple with recent date

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will satisfy what you need without doing a CTE or ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT TOP 1 email, rawEmail, Status
FROM TestToDelete 
WHERE status IN (11, 22)
GROUP BYrawEmail, email, status 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
ORDER BY MAX(validationDate) DESC
```

Comment: But top 1 return only one row. I need all rows that occurs 3 or more times and if it will be two same tuples I want the recent

Comment: You need to edit your question then.  It only shows 1 record being returned.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your current query doesn't do what you express.  You need to take the date into account.  To get rows that have 3 of the same status records on the most recent date:

```
select ttd.*
from (select ttd.*,
             count(*) over (partition by email, rawemail, cast(ValidationDate as date)) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by email, rawemail order by cast(ValidationDate as date) desc) as seqnum
      from TestToDelete ttd
      where status in ('11', '22')
     ) ttd
where seqnum = 1 and cnt >= 3;
```

If you just want the emails and status, use:

```
select distinct email, rawemail, status
```

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you want to know if the three most recent records all have the same status.  This is easier:

```
select email, rawemail, max(status)
from (select ttd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by email, rawemail         
                                 order by ValidationDate desc) as seqnum
      from TestToDelete ttd
      where status in ('11', '22')
     ) ttd
where seqnum <= 3
group by email, rawemail
having min(status) = max(status)
```

Comment: my current query do exactly what I want. But I want to minimize number of subqueries